# Paypal integration to android application using paypal sdk: PaymentActivity class issue

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, in-app-billing

PaymentActivity is unable to get any of these method. i have registered it in menifest file .i haved added the paypal sdk to lib folder.can anyone help me??I have attached the image which is showing the the error i am having.thanx in advance.[image]

Comment: hi am also now working on paypal please provide some help if you solve your problem please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was following the below given tutorial and it is no more valid because several changes in **PayPal SDK** have been made.
https://devblog.paypal.com/working-with-the-new-android-sdk/

if some wants to integrate the **PayPal SDK** for its **inapp** payments he/she can use following sample app:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/tree/master/SampleApp

Comment: Note the link you give is about Braintree v.zero SDK. We can read on Paypal doc: "Braintree v.zero is available for merchants in the United States, Canada, Australia, Europe, Singapore, Hong Kong, Malaysia and New Zealand. In legal terms, you have to be domiciled in a supported country."

Answer (score 1):

Integrating paypal is very with the official paypal sdk. First create a sandbox account and a rest api app at paypal developers website. Now in your android studio add the paypal sdk. You can use the following code for your gradle file.

```
compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.2'
```

Now for the java part you can use the following code for paypal.

```
//Paypal Configuration Object
private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
        // Start with mock environment.  When ready, switch to sandbox (ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
        // or live (ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
        .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
        .clientId(PayPalConfig.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID)
```

Add the above code inside your class. And you need to start paypal service inside onCreate() method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
startService(intent);
```

Paypal is configured now to accept payment you can use the following code.

```
private void getPayment() {
    //Getting the amount from editText
    paymentAmount = editTextAmount.getText().toString();

    //Creating a paypalpayment 
    PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(paymentAmount)), "USD", "Simplified Coding Fee",
            PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

    //Creating Paypal Payment activity intent 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

    //putting the paypal configuration to the intent 
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

    //Puting paypal payment to the intent 
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

    //Starting the intent activity for result
    //the request code will be used on the method onActivityResult 
    startActivityForResult(intent, PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Also don't forget to stop the service on onDestroy method. 
Source: **[Android Paypal Integration Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-paypal-integration-tutorial/)**

Comment: First part of your code I think it's .clientId(PayPalConfiguration.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID) despite of .clientId(PayPalConfig.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID). Also, in SDK 2.14.4, seems PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE is unknow and you must use REQUEST_PAYPAL_PAYMENT.